# Deno read access to CWD

Tags: deno

How can I allow read access to CWD (current working directory) used by `Deno.cwd()`?
**I want explicit permission only for CWD.** I don't want to allow every read with plain `--allow-read` flag.

I've tried to pass `CWD` as a parameter but it doesn't work.

```
deno run --allow-read=CWD index.ts
```

```
Uncaught PermissionDenied: read access to <CWD>, run again with the --allow-read flag
```

Index.ts is just:

```
console.log(Deno.cwd());
```

I am using *deno 1.2.0*.

Comment: What about `deno run --allow-read=. index.ts` ?

Comment: @ford04 It works but it **also allows to read any file in currently working directory**. It is better than allow to read anything but if there is any solution which grants access only to `cwd()` (or any other way to get cwd path) I would be much happier.

Comment: As your command is working while reproducing it, I saw there are granularity options. Is there access like writing happening or reading outside of cwd, that could prevent the execution?

Comment: @lotype Not sure what you mean but currently there is only `Deno.cwd()` in `index.ts` but I will need to use `--allow-access` for different files. Something like `--allow-access=path/to/file,another/path,cwd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That actually depends on the OS you are using.

In Windows, you can use

> deno run --allow-read=%cd% index.ts

In Ubuntu bash

> deno run --allow-read=$PWD index.ts

Answer (score 6):

```js
deno run --allow-read=./ index.ts
```

The relative route `./` will allow you to access everything inside the folder in which `index.ts` is in. Best practices however are to use more fine-grained/specific permissions

As pointed out before https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/permissions#permissions-allow-list